# Monitoring for New USB Controllers in Windows - Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been trying to see if there is a method to consistently monitor for the connection of new USB Devices ( Not all of these are going to be external drives or flash drives ).

Originally I was looking at possibly putting a script together that will run upon start up that creates a scheduled task that will wait for an event of a device being connected then running a script to handle that devices properties as needed.

I haven't been able to find the proper Event ID nor Task Trigger to make this a reality. Does anyone have another idea of how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright after digging further there is a way to watch,

Creating a Scheduled task that has a Trigger set to "On an event"

```
Log: Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational
Source: DriverFrameworks-UserMode
Event ID: 2003
```

It will monitor for when the UMDF Host Process asks for drivers for the new device, which will happen every time a new USB device is loaded.